# Able to send outgoing emails, but not internal

Tags: mail, ssmtp

I've installed ssmtp and configured /etc/ssmtp.conf file and can successfully send outgoing emails, but I cannot send anything internally, i.e. whenever I type `mail sergiy`, which is my actual username on the machine, I can write and send a message, but I still get "No new mail".

Then a few minutes later postmaster in my actual, web-based mail will send a "Delivery Status Notification(Failure)" message. Neither `mail sergiy@localhost` works.

Basically, I want to be able to receive mail on my laptop, not just send it.

I know I can check my web mail with `mutt -f imaps://user@imapserver.example.com`, but this is not what I'm trying to accomplish here.

Also, I've been getting emails of this type when I have root equal to my email address (in the file /etc/ssmtp/ssmpt.conf):

```
Subject: Cron <smmsp@sergiy-Satellite-L455D> test -x /etc/init.d/sendmail && /usr/share/sendmail/sendmail cron-msp
```

And here is the message itself:

```
/usr/share/sendmail/sendmail: 899: /usr/share/sendmail/sendmail: /usr/sbin/sendmail-msp: not found
```

What does cron keep complaining about here?

**Additional information**: According to [this page](http://dsl.org/cookbook/cookbook_38.html) (namely system mail) if you execute `mail user`, mailx assumes localhost, so you should be able to mail yourself or another user on your system. On my laptop neither my account, nor another account can receive mail if I do it this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you installed more than one MTA on your system, now or in the past, you might have leftovers of those installs.
As suggested [elsewhere](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1557127), try:

```
   sudo apt-get purge sendmail sendmail-bin
```

Make sure that the following dependencies - sendmail-base,sendmail-cf and sendmail-bin - are removed.  Then reinstall sendmail.

If you have Postfix installed, you may not need to reinstall sendmail-bin.
HTH

FOLLOW-UP:
sSMTP is only meant to send email to a mail hub. To the best of my knowledge you cannot use it for anything else. So, either you setup your machine as a mail server or you start using an outside mail hub.
Installing PostFix would be a way of acheiving what you want though. If you do so I would recommend you first uninstall ssmtp.

Comment: I tried to remove sendmail as you suggested. The output is this: Package 'sendmail' is not installed, so not removed. In fact, in Ubuntu Software Center it says sendmail not installed, and if i try to install, it says i need to remove ssmtp. Postfix isn't installed either. My plan is to try installing it tomorrow and configure, and see what happens.

Comment: See Follow-Up 1.

Comment: Follow-UP 1 -> FOLLOW-UP